# add a function to the object of property through property decorator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, intern

Is there any way to add a function to the object of the property from its property decorator. I tried to do so but was unable to get reference of the property's object inside decorator. 
I'm working on a UI automation project using Intern js version 4.I've implemented Page Object Model to do so. What i'm trying to achieve here is

- pass the xpath of div containing the validation message to page object of 
  textbox through property decorator.
- From inside property decorator,add a function in page object of textbox to 
  get the visible text from that div  .

Here's what I've tried so far:

ClientPage.ts

```
export class ClientPage extends AbstractSearchPage implements LandingPage {
  @Validate({xpath: '//sumit/shrestha'})
  public clientId: TextBox;
  constructor(remote: any) {
    super(remote)
    this.clientId = new TextBox(remote,'//*[@id="clientId"]')
    this.dataGrid = new DataGrid(remote, '//table[@id="Table"]')
    this.searchBtn = '//*[@id="search"]';
  }

  getPageUrl(): string {
    return '#/clients/clients'
  };
}
```

TextBox.ts

```
export class TextBox extends InputElement {
constructor(remote: any, locator: any) {
    super(remote, locator);
}
async  enterValue(input: string) {
    await this.remote.findByXpath(this.locator).clearValue().type(input);
}
async  clearValue() {
    await this.remote.findByXpath(this.locator).clearValue()
    // return Promise.resolve(this);
}
}
```

Validate.ts

```
export function Validate(config: any) {
var remote = getRemote();
return function (target: Object, property: string | symbol) {
    /*
   // I thought target is reference to Textbox object but it refers to 
   // ClientPage object and even clientpage object here (target) shows only 
   // functions when doing console.log(target)
    */
    console.log(config.xpath)
    target.prototype.requiredFieldValidation = async function (): Promise<string> {
        await target.enterValue('ddd')
        await  target.clearValue('ddd')
        return await remote.findByXpath(config.xpath).getVisibleText();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`target` is the prototype of the ClientPage there. You should learn, how decorators work. See [my article](https://habrahabr.ru/company/docsvision/blog/310870/)(rus) for example.

If you want to add function to object, stored in the field, there are two ways.

First approach - define get/set accessors, and when value assigned to property, add function to this value.

```
export function Validate(config: any) {
    var remote = getRemote();
    return function (target: Object, property: string | symbol) {
        // Create get/set accessors for the property
        let value;
        let propertyDescription = {
            get: function() { 
                return value;
            },
            set: function(textBox) {
                value = textBox;
                // When textBox assigned to property, add function to object
                textBox.requiredFieldValidation = async function (): Promise<string> {
                    await this.enterValue('ddd')
                    await  this.clearValue('ddd')
                    return await remote.findByXpath(config.xpath).getVisibleText();
                }
            },
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true
        };            
        Object.defineProperty(target, property, propertyDescription);
    }
}
```

There [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20%20function%20Validate(config%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20remote%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20Object%2C%20property%3A%20string%20%7C%20symbol)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Create%20get%2Fset%20accessors%20for%20the%20property%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propertyDescription%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20function(textBox)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20textBox%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20When%20textBox%20assigned%20to%20property%2C%20add%20function%20to%20object%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20textBox.requiredFieldValidation%20%3D%20async%20function%20()%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.sayHello(config)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(target%2C%20property%2C%20propertyDescription)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sayHello(msg)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(msg)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20msg%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Validate(%22test%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20Bar%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0Afoo.bar.requiredFieldValidation()%3B)

Second approach, get property type (class Constructor) with reflect-metadata, and define function in its prototype. You can find example of using reflect-metadata in [example from the article](https://embed.plnkr.co/fcjDyqdK6kG9yPWlTsNB/). It uses type information for performing dependency injection.